# How cloud foundry appy identifies current tenant

Tags: cloud-foundry

Consider I have an application (`app1`) running on cloud foundry that caters to multiple tenants (multiple customers). This app is bound to an instance of database service (`db_inst1`). Now, how does `app1` know which tenant the current user belongs to?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a Cloud Foundry-specific question.  Sounds like you're just talking about an app with multiple users or organizations.  Your database needs to account for this.

Comment: @tomol Do you mean that your app is a service ?

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta Asaf, How do you get the context of the user?